# Merge two pandas dataframes keeping the top ranked rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df_a and df_b are two dataframes that looks like following

```
df_a
A   B       C      D     E
x1  Apple   0.3   0.9    0.6
x1  Orange  0.1   0.5    0.2
x2  Apple   0.2   0.2    0.1
x2  Orange  0.3   0.4    0.9
x2  Mango   0.1   0.2    0.3
x3  Orange  0.3   0.1    0.2


df_b
A   B_new   F    
x1  Apple   0.3  
x1  Mango   0.2  
x1  Orange  0.1   
x2  Apple   0.2   
x2  Orange  0.3     
x2  Mango   0.1  
x3  Orange  0.3  
x3  Mango   0.2  
x3  Apple   0.1
```

I want to merge these two dataframes on column A such that only the rows from column B_new which has the top 'n' values in column F is retained. Where 'n' corresponds to the number of rows corresponding to each unique value of A in df_a.

in short, I want my result to look like the following

```
A   B       C      D     E    B_new    F
x1  Apple   0.3   0.9    0.6  Apple   0.3
x1  Orange  0.1   0.5    0.2  Mango   0.2
x2  Apple   0.2   0.2    0.1  Orange  0.3 
x2  Orange  0.3   0.4    0.9  Apple   0.2
x2  Mango   0.1   0.2    0.3  Mango   0.1
x3  Orange  0.3   0.1    0.2  Orange  0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` + `cumcount` to create a group id for each `DataFrame` Then merge based on that and column `A`

```
dfa['gid'] = dfa.groupby('A').cumcount()
dfb['gid'] = dfb.sort_values('F', ascending=False).groupby('A').cumcount()
dfa.merge(dfb, on=['A', 'gid'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
    A       B    C    D    E  gid   B_new    F
0  x1   Apple  0.3  0.9  0.6    0   Apple  0.3
1  x1  Orange  0.1  0.5  0.2    1   Mango  0.2
2  x2   Apple  0.2  0.2  0.1    0  Orange  0.3
3  x2  Orange  0.3  0.4  0.9    1   Apple  0.2
4  x2   Mango  0.1  0.2  0.3    2   Mango  0.1
5  x3  Orange  0.3  0.1  0.2    0  Orange  0.3
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I also want the column 'E' to be sorted in descending order. Following line doesn't seem to be working  

dfa['gid'] = dfa.sort_values('E', ascending=False).groupby('A').cumcount() 

Any suggestions?

Comment: @iprof0214 Within each group of `A` column `E` is already sorted in descending order, so your sort changes nothing. If you want the final output to be sorted you can add a `.sort_values('E', asending=False)` to the end of the merge. You just need to be careful because if you change the sorting **before** the merge you can impact which rows get merged, since that has the possibility of impacting the ordering of rows within each group, which is all `cumcount` uses to create labels.

Comment: yes you;re right. I soreted the values in df_a based on columns 'A' and 'E' then created the gid column as you suggested and it works. Following is what I did.

dfa = dfa.sort_values(['A','E'], ascending=False)

dfa['gid'] = dfa.groupby('A').cumcount()

dfb['gid'] = dfb.sort_values('F', ascending=False).groupby('A').cumcount()

result = dfa.merge(dfb, on=['A', 'gid'], how='left')